# Instantiate a class to an unknown variable name in python3

Tags: python, class, dynamic, python-3.x

I am trying to get at a way to instantiate a class from an unknown `nodeName` in unknown doms (without using `eval()`).

I want to do something like this pseudocode assuming `node` is a `dom node` in a `dom tree`:

```
# create dom and get a node

class SuperNode(node):
    def __init__(self):
        # do narly node stuff
```

but I want in create the class based on the node name, which would be unknown like this.

```
makeInstance(SuperNode, node.nodeName, node)
```

To clarify, node.nodeName is the name of the node that I want to be the variable name for the instance. So if `node.nodeName = 'clarence'` it would be like instantiating it like this (I'll worry about alphabetizing the node name later to conform with class naming):

```
clarence = SuperNode(node) ''' where node is the node specified 
                               by the name clarence'''
```

The constructor would be something like this if names were known:

```
makeInstance(SuperNode, 'clarence', node) ''' where clarance will be the 
                                              instantiated variable of 
                                              class SuperNode'''
```

This is akin to setting an attribute using setattrib:

```
setattr(class instance, attribute, value)
```

Where attributes can be defined in a variable.

In case there is a question how these names will be accessed, they will be defined in yet another class for the overall dom that can then be inspected.

Is there a way to do this?

An example is an XML file for dogs including elements for dog names, breed, birthday, etc. Each dog will be a class of superNode under my initial dom class with all the attributes "magically" set in each instance of SuperNode

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to initiate a different subclass depending on the xml attributes? Or you want to set attributes on the instance from the xml?  Please make the question more clear.  Give the specific api you want to have.

Comment: Good clarification. Thanks. I want to name the different subclasses depending on the xml attributes (in this case, the name of the node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally came to me what I needed to do, and sadly, the answer is already above (a little humility is always good). When wrapping in an object, just use `setattr`, as in:

```
>>> class SuperClass():
...     def print_hello(self):
...         print('Hello, world!')

>>> class WrapperClass():
...     pass

>>> wrapper = WrapperClass()
>>> setattr(wrapper, 'clarence', SuperClass())

>>> wrapper.clarence.print_hello()
Hello, world!
>>>
```

Actually, I'll be using code within the wrapper-type class so it will be:

```
setattr(self, 'clarence', SuperClass())
```

If you want to do it in global scope, use globals() to assign the value like this:

```
>>> globals()['clarence'] = SuperClass()
>>> clarence.print_hello()
Hello, world!
```